# AHK Cannot ControlClick on hidden elements in nested child window

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

I'm trying to automate a many clicking process, just to narrow it to the user input.
I encountered problems in controlClicking interface elements, which seems not to be standard Windows GUI elements.
When pointing them with WinSpy they don't appear as separate buttons, but I can point the whole child Window which is drawn in the main program window.

As on pic1, I pointed the whole window and I can find each tab/button by it's text inside and on pic2 I can inspect the ClassNN of that element and it's ID.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

As far as clicking other buttons in the main menu bar of the program works, a simple:

```
ControlClick, ClaTab_01000000H26, WindowName
```

doesn't work. I think during the day, and many possibilities I tried, I could ControlClick the above button by pointing it with its ID, but that ID changes every instance. I could confirm that tomorrow if it works by ID.

Of course I tried SetControlDelay -1 and ,NN option. But don't take that for granted, I can try any of your suggestions tomorrow.

Both tabs marked with purple color, are to find in the Windows->SiblingWindows tab. I really don't want using x,yCoords (that actually work), but I need the script to be as reliable as possible.

So my questions are:

1. Am I missing something or you have any suggestions how to click that elements?
2. Is it correct, that no matter how deep the child windows get (one has buttons to open another on top of it), all the time the WinName stays the same pointing to the main program ***.exe?
3. Could you provide an example from the web or yours, to find an element's ID by providing the text attached to the button (pic1-red line and also pic2 in "text")?
4. I also cannot maximize the child window. Double clicking it works, but I can't find the appropriate ClassNN of the window to call.
5. Could you provide an example, how to use the Messages tab? I assume, if I find the button as on the pictures, I could send a message with controlClick and see if there's a reaction?

Answer (score 0):

1.Ugh. I found the solution, which is awesome, but a little frustrating that with a bit of luck I tried another aproach that's not that logical for a newbie like me:

instead:

```
ControlClick, ClaTab_01000000H6, ahk_class ClaWin01000000H_2,,,, NA
```

it's just

```
ControlFocus, ClaTab_01000000H6, ahk_class ClaWin01000000H_2,,,, NA
```

2._Yep. One child window creates another and another and another, but winTitle stays the same. In my case:

```
ahk_class ClaWin01000000H_2
```

3._Code below returns the handle/ID of the element you specify. Change ClaTab and ClaWin to your chouice.

```
ControlGet, OutputVar, hwnd,, ClaTab_01000000H1, ahk_class ClaWin01000000H_2
MsgBox, %OutputVar%`
```

**Probably to be continued.**

I highly recomend to both use

- WinSpy https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28220
- SimpleSpy https://www.the-automator.com/downloads/simple-spy/

First one has lots of useful information and the window tab provides information of hidden buttons/windows. Second one in a more clear way indicates the parent window and its class.